# Troubleshooting the REPWEIGHTS option in surveyreg analysis (SAS)

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS and the documentation for repweights seems to be kind of limited. I'm trying to weight a nationally-representative survey, but my replicate weights are producing an error (red in the code, no effect on the results if I pull them out) and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Here's my sample:

```
proc surveyreg data=ffm.premodel;
  weight m1wt;
  repweights m1wt_rep1--m1wt_rep33;
  where natflag=1;
  class lb;
  model wr9 = lb ed inc / solution;
  lsmeans lb / cov pdiff;
  output out=ffm.wr9_1 residual=res; 
  run;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the error?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is one single hyphen for specifying something like replicate weights:

repweights m1wt_rep1-m1wt_rep33;

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with rep weights, it's just a different kind of variable list- but this certainly could be the issue if they're not consecutive on the data file.

Comment: No it didn't have to be specifically replicate weights, but any ordered variable. Anyhow, hard to tell without a log